# Dynamically sized views in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints, autolayout

I have a UITableViewCell that has two views in it that are dynamically sized. How would I handle something like this in terms of the constraints used, where to actually set the dynamic heights (height for row? cell for index?). I've been cracking away at this for a few hours but can't seem to figure it out, thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to describe the two dynamic heights more. Like are they based on their contents? Or are they some percentage of the cell's overall height?

Comment: They are based on their content. Dynamic height 1 has a some static elements and then a dynamically sized UILabel, same with the dynamic height 2 view.

Answer (score 0):

If the dynamic heights are just based on content, constraints like this `"V:|[fx1][dh1][dh2][fx2]|"` will get you unpredictable results. Autolayout will try it's best, but one of the dynamic views will "giveup" it's intrinsic size to fill up the space.

I think you have two options:

#### Give the first "dynamic" view a higher content hugging priority

This would perhaps work if you need all cells to be the same height in your table.

```
[self.dh1 setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                            forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];

[self.dh2 setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
                            forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

#### Size the whole cell according to it's content

Don't think of it as having to fit stuff into the cell. Size the cell to fit it's content instead.

Use constraints like this: `"V:|[fx1(20)][dh1][dh2][fx2(20)]"` ... without 'anchoring' the last fixed view to the bottom

Then, in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, layout out the cell in the background and measure it.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];
  // etc...

  [cell setNeedsLayout];
  [cell layoutIfNeeded];

  return cell.fx2.frame.origin.y + cell.fx2.frame.size.height;
}
```